# SCOTUS Cases Concerning Men's Healthcare

Tags: united-states, us-supreme-court

As it says in the title, I am wondering if there have been any SCOTUS (or lower courts, if none at that level) cases concerning men's healthcare in the same way that cases like *Roe v. Wade* and the recent *Little Sisters of the Poor Saints Peter and Paul Home v. Pennsylvania* concern women's healthcare.

I have tried a quick google search, but found nothing but references to women's care, or at least nothing obviously fitting. I also suspect that the scope here is far beyond my very limited knowledge about case research.

Comment: Part of the problem is defining the question. What is "men's healthcare", as a special subclass of "healthcare"? AFAIK all sex-specific medical rulings pertain to pregnancy, specifically abortion and pregnancy. What is an imaginable male-specific healthcare legal issue?

Comment: @user6726 circumcision.

Comment: @user6726 chemical castration

Comment: I encourage the OP to incorporate these suggestions, and also encourage other examples. E.g. what are the laws regarding circumcision (or prostrate surgery), then the question of whether SCOTUS has an opinion can be addressed.

Comment: A vasectomy is probably the closest analogue.